# Question about asymmetry of chi-square distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be a set of i.i.d. chi-square random variables with $k$ degrees of freedom. Consider the statistic $\arg\max_i\{|X_i/k - 1|\}=X_{\alpha}$. I wonder about the probability that $X_{\alpha} = X_{\text{max}}$, rather than $X_{\text{min}}$? Does it change if $k$ gets large?

I suspect that it may be very, very difficult to get a precise answer to the above questions.

**So I would like to ask the simpler question**: can we at least say that it is more likely that $X_{\alpha} = X_{\text{max}}$? Simulations seem to indicate yes. Is there a heuristic reason why?

Answer (score 1):

From my simulations, it is clear that the answer is going to depend strongly on $k$ and $n$.  For all $k$, as $n$ increases, $\Pr[X_\alpha = X_{(n)}]$ increases:  the probability that the given statistic is the maximum order statistic becomes increasingly likely.  The effect of increasing $k$ is to make the rate at which this probability increases as a function of $n$ slower.

Given some more thought, one might be able to prove these claims mathematically.

---

We can get an exact probability for the case $k = 2$ (which is exponential), and for general $n$:  the joint distribution of $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is $$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}e^{-(x+y)/2}(e^{-x/2} - e^{-y/2})^{n-2}, \quad 0 \le x < y.$$  The probability that $|X_{(1)} - 2| > |X_{(n)} - 2|$ is equivalent to $$p(n) = \Pr[X_{(1)} + X_{(n)} < 4] = \int_{x=0}^2 \int_{y=x}^{4-x} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$  For specific values of $n$, we have $$\begin{align*} p(2) &= 1-3e^{-2} \\ p(3) &=  1 - 6e^{-2} + 8e^{-3} - 3e^{-4} \\ p(4) &= 1 - 6e^{-2} + 15e^{-4} + 2e^{-6} \\ p(5) &= 1 - \tfrac{20}{3}e^{-2} + 30 e^{-4} - \tfrac{128}{3}e^{-5} + 20e^{-6} - \tfrac{5}{3}e^{-8}. \end{align*}$$  Only the first two are greater than $1/2$.

Comment: To be clear, I restricted myself at the end to a simple question about which order statistic it will be. Are you ever seeing that the order statistic can (with higher probability) be the minimum? It seems to me that there might be a good argument for this.

Comment: Yes.  In my simulations, for very small sample sizes (e.g., $n = 2$), it is more likely that $|X_{(1)}/k - 1| > |X_{(n)}/k - 1|$.  This appears to be true for all degrees of freedom, although as $k \to \infty$, this probability tends to $1/2$.

Comment: I observed the asymptotic result, but not the small-k result. Do you have a sense for why it happens for large k?

Comment: After more investigation, it appears that only when $n \in \{2, 3\}$ that $\Pr[X_\alpha = X_{(1)}] > 1/2$, regardless of $k$.

Comment: What happened to the gamma and incomplete gamma functions in your derivation of the order statistics?

Comment: @Helmut When $k = 2$, the chi-square distribution is an exponential distribution with mean $2$; this is what allows the computation to be simple.  For other degrees of freedom, the joint distribution of the minimum and maximum order statistics is more complicated.  However, the overall result seems to hold:  $\Pr[X_\alpha = X_{(1)}] > 1/2$ if and only if $n \in \{2,3\}$, for all positive integer-valued $k$.

Comment: Ok, I see that you just did it for $k=2$. So the overall problem is still unsolved, though as both of our simulations show it does seem to hold in general.